# Flexbox and Firefox flex-basis

Tags: css, html, firefox, flexbox

I've been doing some browser testing on my flexbox layout, and it looks great in all evergreen browsers except Firefox. It should look like this - all Grid-Cell items being given an auto flex-basis based on the item content.[image]
However on Firefox 51 (macOS) it's all one huge single column.
[image]

Here's a Codepen: http://codepen.io/toddsby/pen/jyZabo with the full example.

Here's the code I'm using

**CSS**

```
.Grid {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;  
  display: -webkit-flex;  
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Grid-fit > .Grid-cell {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto; 
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto; 
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="Grid Grid-fit">
  <li class="Grid-cell">
    ...{content}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I looked through [Philip Walton's Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) but none of those suggestions made a difference. Anyone else run into this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The key was @Syden's mention of browsers handling SVG rendering differently. It appears Firefox requires a height attribute to properly render the element. The simple solution to the broken layout was updating the .item svg css selector with a max-height property as follows:

```
.item svg {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Here's the full code example w/ bugfix on Codepen:
http://codepen.io/toddsby/pen/PWRqXO

Firefox now rendering layout correctly: [image]

Related Note: Here's a great explanation of how the SVG preserveAspectRatio works: http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/svg-and-the-preserveaspectratio-property.php

Answer (score 4):

The issue lies on the svg percentage, since they are floating, dimensions are not being considered:

```
svg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Change it to desired `px`, but note not all browsers render svgs the same:

```
svg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Here's a code pen that maintains the layout in all browsers, although firefox has a bit more margin-bottom due to svg height.

Note also the `.Grid-cell` typo as mentioned by Michael_B.

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJQBNJ**

This is Safari:

[image]

You can reduce that row gap by lowering height to let's say `200px`:

[image]

But Firefox will not let you impact height only and will reduce width as well:

[image]

So you could try to workaround that gap by removing `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` on the svg and re-styling it or leave it in all browsers with a moderate gap:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this exploration!! It really helped me narrow the issue to the SVG render differing between browsers. The fix was actually very simple, for Firefox, I just needed to add `max-height: 300px;` to the .item svg selector!

Answer (score 0):

In your demo, one key selector isn't working:

```
.Grid-cell (CSS) vs .Grid-Cell (HTML)
```

Hence, the `flex: 0 0 auto` isn't working, in any case.

Once that is fixed, try using `flex: 1` instead of `flex: 0 0 auto`.

Comment: This is not correct. `flex: 1` and `flex: 0 0 auto` are not equivalent. Please see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property. Flex shorthand is flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis.

Comment: @toddsby, I never said they were equivalent. I was suggesting a switch to a different rule.

Comment: your suggestion doesn't address the problem and results in a completely different and undesired layout.

Comment: Fine. But that's not what your first comment was about. And I tested the solution in Firefox and it worked as I understood the question.

Comment: A simple back-and-forth would have been more constructive than a wrong assumption and a down vote.

Comment: Not to mention I identified an important error in your code.